# Methods Memory management in iOS under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

What happens Memory wise if I keep calling this method?
(Please don’t comment the code, it is just a thought example. )

```
-(NSMutableArray*)searchForItemsWithString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSString *baseUrl = @"http://www.myService.com/";

    NSURL *tempUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrl, searchString]];

    NSMutableArray *tempResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:tempUrl];

    return tempResultArray;
}
```

Will `tempResultArray` keep increasing the reference count, or will ARC do the magic after `tempResultArray` has been returned, and dealloc it?

Comment: The whole point of ARC is that memory management is done for you. There is nothing to worry about if you keep calling this method.

Comment: "What happens Memory wise if I keep calling this method?" You can and should use Instruments to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC <s>will</s> **may** (see comments) put an `autorelease` call on `tempResultArray` before returning it. What happens to it after that is up to the rest of your program. The next time you call this method, a new `tempResultArray` will be created and the process repeats.

Comment: The ARC compiler *may* add an autorelease call. The ARC optimizer is quite clever to remove unnecessary retain/release/autorelease calls (with cross-method optimization). And even at runtime the called function can inspect the callers stack and decide if an autorelease is necessary.

Comment: Just another question:  What happens to tempResultArray, if it is  passed via the return to a property with a strong pointer to a NSMtableArray object. (ex. self.result) ?

Comment: It is sent a `retain` message when it is assigned (or equivalent, ARC permitting). But remember, that is not the same pointer as the one in the scope of your method. That one is a stack pointer, and it goes away when that stack frame does. The array itself is on the heap, and stick around until its retain count goes to 0.